# C# cast generic to object

Tags: c#, casting

I faced problem, related with cast.
I have domain class

```
public class Product: Entity<int>
{
  //....
}
```

and i have wrapper

```
public class  CommonWrapperDTO<T> where T : Entity<int>
{
   public T content {get; set;}
   public string[] Information {get; set;}
}
```

so, I need convert

```
//variable "result" have type a CommonWrapperDTO<Product>
var resultValue = result as CommonWrapperDTO<Entity<int>>;
```

but `as` returns `null`.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the result wasn't `null`, it would allow you to assign any `Entity<int>` to the `content` property of the returned object. Are you doing this only to access the `Information` property? What were you planning to do with `resultValue`?

Comment: @Groo not sure about this close; In the other answer OP needed the list function and so the workaround was to go through linq.  In this case OP does not need this and as such using a covariant interface could work.  (Assuming that he doesn't need the setter of the content property)

Comment: @Taemyr: perhaps the OP can add some details, that's why I asked that couple of questions, we can easily reopen it if needed.

Comment: Thanks for response, in my case I was helped by the use of covariaте interface